# Is a public readonly List<T> bad design?

Tags: c#, oop, software-design

I am currently writing an application that builds a connection to some sort of Service, gets Data in the form of a few `DataTable` objects and then is supposed to show it to the user.
In order to store the Data I get I made a class called `DataStorage` which has a `List<DataTable>`. Other classes need to be able to edit this List, for example adding objects that are needed or removing them if the user finds them unnecessary. I also have to be able to clear it, should I need a completely new set of data.
I could give the `DataStorage` methods for that but since the `List<T>` already offers these, I see no point in encapsulating it like that. So I made it `readonly` to ensure nobody tries to assign a new object - or even worse, `null` - and made the access modifier `public`.
Is this sort of design acceptable or should I always protect fields from direct access, no matter what?

Comment: I suggest declaring it  as `internal`, not `public`: some (approved) classes can edit the list, but not anyone.

Comment: Do you not need to *track* the additions and removals?

Comment: `List<T>` isn't thread-safe. Does that pose an issue for you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no, I do not.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thread safety is an unknown term to me. Wikipedia defines it as A piece of code is thread-safe if it only manipulates shared data structures in a manner that guarantees safe execution by multiple threads at the same time.
Since this just a small tool for showing some data, I don't think multiple threads are a concern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General speaking you should allways take the most general type to reduce any tight coupling and to provide only those members you actually need access to. Having said this in some situations it might be better to use an `ICollection` instead which provides access to basic methods such as `Add`, `Remove` and `Clear`.

However making the collection `readonly` or even better a Get-only property is probably a good idea and nothing can be said against this.

Comment: Agreed, it should be exposed as an `ICollection<T>`. It should also be exposed through a property and not as a naked field.

Comment: So since I basically only need the three methods we both mentioned, having my storage implement `ICollection<T>` is a better way than having a public `List<T>` simply because `List<T>` offers a lot of stuff I don't need?

Comment: @Wilsu Consider that in the future, you could technically want to change how the class internally saves objects. If other classes expect a list, you're going to have to rewrite all of them at that point. However, if they just expect an ICollection, you can switch to any other ICollection without affecting any other class, and even if you implemented your own solution, you would just have to implement ICollection, not make a subclass of List. This is a good reason for always trying to stick to the most general interface.

Comment: @Tobberoth You're right, I tend to forget that. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

We should be very careful with `public` which means `public` - whatever.
Do you let any class behave in such a way?

```
  public class Offender {
    ...
    public void Offend(YourClass value) {
      ...
      // In the middle of my routine I've ruined your class
      value.Data.Clear();
      value.Data.Add(someStuff);
      ...
    }
  }
```

I suggest restricting *full access* to `Data` to trusted classes only:

```
  public class YourClass {
    // Approved classes (i.e. from your routine) can write, delete, clear... 
    internal readonly List<Data> m_Data = new List<Data>();

    // All the other can only read 
    public IReadOnlyList<Data> Data {
      get {
        return m_Data;
      }
    }
    ...
    // If you let (in some cases) add, delete, clear to untrusted class 
    // just add appropriate methods:
    public void Add(Data data) {
      // Here you can validate the provided data, check conditions, state etc.
    }
  }
```

Comment: In my case, making it internal wouldn't make much of a difference since I only have one assembly here. You are perfectly correct for larger projects though, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You should append that in order to change the elements within the internal list you may create some wrapper-methods that work on that list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish a collection with add/remove capability, it is the best if you override the `Collection<T>` (or `ObservableCollection<T>`) class, which is very similar to `List<T>`, but you can override and thus control the add/remove/replace operations. And yes, you can make it public via a get-only property.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyCollection myCollection = new MyCollection();

    public IList<MyElement> Collection { get { return myCollection; } }
}

internal class MyCollection: Collection<MyElement>
{
    // by overriding InsertItem you can control Add and Insert
    protected override InsertItem(int index, MyElement item)
    {
        if (CheckItem(item))
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
        throw new ArgumentException("blah");
    }

    // similarly, you can override RemoveItem to control Remove and RemoveAt,
    // and SetItem to control the setting by the indexer (this[])
}
```

Comment: I know that I can use a get only property but in this particular case it gives me now benefit. But it's a very interesting piece of code you have there which might prove useful in the future.